# How to issue a statement containing single quotes from a bash script

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I tried to execute the following mysql command in one of my scripts:

```
mysql -e 'show global status like 'open_files''
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because of the single quotes around the string `'open_files'`.

How can I issue a command like this, that contains a single quote?

Comment: If this line is throwing an error message, can you post it?

Comment: use `"open files"` instead

Answer (score 6):

Use double quote outside.

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uxxxxx -pxxxxx -A databasename -e "show global status like 'open_files'"
```

or the reverse way:

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uxxxxx -pxxxxx -A databasename -e 'show global status like "open_files"'
```

or you could escape the single quote.

And you are using `LIKE`, didn't you miss the wild char `%`?